# PostgreSQL connection pool connection limits?

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling

I'm using a PostgreSQL DB on DigitalOcean and I'm not really into the devops world. You can call me a noob :P

To me, it's not quite clear how connection pools work in terms of connection limits.

I get that I can assign connections to a connection pool, but I'm not sure on how the pool makes use of them. If I have a connection with 5 connections assigned, but then my application has 10 clients, will I not reach a connection limit? Can I basically have unlimited connections with any sized connection pool, since they will queue up, or what are the limits of clients when using a connection pool?

I tried playing around with pgbench and a large amount of client's and it seemed to me like I was unable to cause the `FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections` error when using a pool.

Any explanations are appreciated :D

**Update**:

I'm using a [transaction connection pool](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/postgresql/how-to/manage-connection-pools/#pooling-modes) available for managed DB's in DigitalOcean.

Comment: If would be helpful to know what pooling software you are using and how you configured it. Add this information as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added the info :D